# Why is it bad to resturn a document from Couchbase View`s

Tags: view, couchbase, emit

I am trying to enter Couchbase world and learning things about a views. 
Several time in presentations and demos i heard its bad to return whole doc in from a view:

```
emit(meta.id, doc);
```

My question is why? What should i return then and how can i grab a proper values of the document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bad idea because it's actually counterproductive. Writing a document to the view means it will be stored on disk with the view index itself. You pay the IO price for writing the document to disk again (a duplicate of the original key/value doc), and you pay it again for reading it at query time. Because views queries are served from disk (or the file system cache), you will never take advantage of the integrated cache layer to retrieve the document faster. In short, in average it will be faster to get the document ID from the view and retrieve the document by id, than it is to just read the whole document from the view. This is especially true for operations on multiple documents.

Comment: In addition to the front end price, you will pay the price when you re balance the cluster because of the storage issues that David mentioned. So it becomes a maintenance issue as rebalances will take longer.

Comment: The fact is that it doesn't make sense given couchbase architecture. Perhaps the documentation needs to be more clear on this because I feel that this is a serious problem out there.

Comment: @theMayer: Are you saying that instead we should return only the document ids and have the client query each of those documetns seprately to get the full result? Wouldn't that cause a performance bottleneck on the clientside. Say my view returns 30 document ids, I'd really not want my client to make 30 network calls to get the full result.

Comment: @theMayer: btw, I completely understand the issues you mentioned in the answer - I'm just curious as to what is the best practice in the scenario where my client needs the entire documents as a result of the query.

Comment: more details at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813135/returning-full-document-from-result-of-a-view-query-fo-couchbase

Comment: @ArnabChakraborty - it is actually more efficient by at least an order of magnitude to query the additional document details at the server. This is not true from a remote client with internet latency - however, Couchbase should never be opened up directly to the internet - your web service should be doing this automatically. CB also has a "batch" service for multiple item get.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad because it's a large drain on resources, views will often update and overwrite indices, so if you are writing a whole doc repeatedly it's going to require a large amount of processor time and disk I/O (along with filesystem cache).

Therefore, it is recommended (and far more efficient) to have the view return the doc.id and then use the standard `get` procedure to return the whole doc.