# Returning full document from result of a view query for Couchbase

Tags: c#, couchbase

I'm trying to build a filter view, where I can filter documents based on a column range. My map function looks something like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(!doc.tombstone) {
    emit([doc.effectiveDateTime]);
  }
}
```

When I query this view from code, the result only has the keys and not the documents.

I can think of the following ways to solve this, and need help deciding which one could work.

1. **setIncludeDocs**: Exploring the documentation a little bit, I came accross this [java code snippet](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/views-from-apps.html) where the [setIncludeDocs](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-java-client-1.1-dp4/com/couchbase/client/protocol/views/Query.html%23setIncludeDocs%28boolean%29) method is invoked on the query to return full documents with the result. 
   It looks promising, unfortunately I cannot find an equivalent of this method in the C# SDK.
2. **Query individual documents**: Emit the document id as the value like `emit([doc.effectiveDateTime], meta.id);` and query each document separately from the client side. I do not want to use this approach as the client would end up making multiple calls to the server to get the full result set and would cause performance issues in the client side.
3. **Emit entire document**: I could emit the entire document as the value in the emit statement of the mapper like this: `emit([doc.effectiveDateTime], doc);`. This approach has the advantage that the client has to make only one call to get the result set. But I'm not sure about the implications this has on the size of the index. Given that my mapper will work on most of the documents, **would the index size grow** or will couchbase be able to optimize it internally somehow?
4. **Query documents inside the reduce function (not sure if this is feasible)**: If I modify the mapper to emit document ids as values and have a mechanism to query and get the entire document from inside the reducer, then I should be able form the result set inside the reducer. **Are there any javascript apis which can be used to acces the database from inside the reducer?**

Any advice regarding the above points or any new ones would be much appreciated.

Comment: which version of the C# SDK are you using?

Comment: concerning 3. *yes* the index will definitely grow. couchbase should automatically include the document's ID as part of the view result metadata though, so 2. should be at least partially supported on the various SDK versions... for instance Java 2.0 SDK has a method `getDocument` that internally uses this metadata and issue a `get` on the key...

Comment: Good question, CB does have a multi-item get in the C# library as well as a built-in c# method to get the full doc of the current item in your iteration of view results. Will post a complete answer when I have time this evening.

Comment: @SimonBaslé I'm using version C# SDK version 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C# SDK 2.x, your best bet is option 2. with a twist: the query engine already emits the document's ID as part of its response metadata, no need for your view to emit it.

Use the `Rows` method of your `IViewResult` to iterate over rows. This gives you a `ViewRow<T>` of each row. On `ViewRow`, just get the `Id`property. You can then `get` the associated document the usual way.

Comment: Just curious, would it be best to get them individually or with a bulk get?

Comment: A bulk get could definitely give you better performance, but both are ok

Comment: I get that both are OK, but with the bulk get perform better?

Comment: It wouldn't, because internally a bulk get just does parallel single gets. The SDK bulk get method is syntactic sugar that also lets you specify the degree of parallelism instead of doing it manually. The relevant implementation is here (lines 1325-1395) https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/master/Src/Couchbase/CouchbaseBucket.cs

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify. A bulk get is always better than *sequential* single gets, but it will have the same performance as going parallel single gets manually (such as with a Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach) because that's exactly what it does internally anyway.